# SVPullToRefresh not triggering the action handler when pushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

The first trigger goes ok, but after that, if I try to pull it down, it always shows its still loading.

here is my simple code example on my UITableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __weak StoresViewController * bSelf = self;
    [self.tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
        [bSelf callStoresService];
    }];
    [self.tableView triggerPullToRefresh];
}

- (void)callStoresService {
    [self.tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];
}
```

Adding a breakpoint to `[self.tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];` I can see it never gets called again...

I have an old project with almost the same code and its working... anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am only developing for iOS 6, I decided to use the native refresh:

on my viewDidLoad:

```
// managing pullToRefresh
UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull down to refresh"];
[refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refresh;
[self refreshView:refresh];
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
```

Then create a refreshView method:

```
-(void)refreshView:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {
    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refreshing..."];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM HH:mm:ss"];

    // do what you need

    NSString *lastUpdated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last update: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lastUpdated];
}
```

dont forget to call `[refresh endRefreshing];` when your are done